# cant run electron on win10 ubuntu subsystem

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, suid

i have a repo for an electron project ive been able to run in ubuntu subsystem before fine, im on a new pc now and having trouble. I already ran npm i, but when I run `electron .` i get this err:

```
martin@DESKTOP-URPCCBK:/mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager$ npm start

> drag-and-drop@1.0.0 start /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager
> electron .

[5094:0907/143024.016724:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

so i ran

```
sudo chown root /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
```

and

```
sudo chmod 4755 /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
```

then ran npm start again, and get:

```
martin@DESKTOP-URPCCBK:/mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager$ npm start

> drag-and-drop@1.0.0 start /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager
> electron .

[5120:0907/143308.127280:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/electron-upload-manager/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

I did what the error asked, but still got the error? Ive tried removing my node_modules, reinstalling with npm i, running apt-get update, installing electron globally but still am getting this err

Comment: Hmm, have you enabled file perms on drvfs?

Comment: what is drvfs ?

Comment: drvfs is a filesystem that lets wsl/windows cooperate on windows files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable metadata on DrvFs. Put this in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

After this, chmod/chown should work on windows files. See this [Microsoft blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/) for more details.

Comment: i did this and restarted my computer but it didnt make a difference

Comment: Try chown/chmoding again. To verify that it has the right perms, you can `ls -la` the file.

Comment: I guess this answer is right, I was trying combinations of reinstall electron, set permissions `sudo chown root:$USER ./node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox`, `sudo chmod 4755 ./node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox`. Now I have a different error `Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied
/home/junior/myapp/node_modules/electron/dist/electron`. For "electron": "^10.1.1", node 10.19.0, npm 6.14.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this command. It is a work-around:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Comment: This worked for me. Could you explain how it works, please!

Answer (score 0):

ill just run it in command prompt instead, got it working fine there